# PHP - How to hide the form after it's submitted

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a domain name check form that i have in a container. After I submit the form the availability of the domain name is checked and a message is shown in the same container as the form. When the message is shown, I want the form and first H2 to disappear. How can i do this?

My code:

```
<div id="domain-name-check">
    <h2>Is uw domeinnaam nog vrij?</h2>
    <form method='post' class="clearfix">
        <input type=text name=domain>
            <select name="suffix">
                <option value=".nl">.nl</option>
                <option value=".be">.be</option>
                <option value=".com">.com</option>
                <option value=".net">.net</option>
                <option value=".org">.org</option>
                <option value=".biz">.biz</option>
                <option value=".info">.info</option>
                <option value=".mobi">.mobi</option>
                <option value=".ws">.ws</option>
                <option value=".cc">.cc</option>
            </select>
            <input type=submit name=proses value=Check>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['proses'])){
        $domain_name = "$_POST[domain]"."$_POST[suffix]";
        $arrHost = @gethostbynamel("$domain_name");
        $date = date('y-m-d');

        if(empty($arrHost)){
            echo "<h2>$domain_name is beschikbaar</h2> <a href='/offerte-aanvragen/".$domain_name."/'>Vraag een offerte aan</a>";
            $availability = "yes";
        }else{
            echo "<h2>$domain_name is helaas bezet</h2> <a href='/offerte-aanvragen/".$domain_name."/verhuizen/'>Verhuis uw domein</a>";
            $availability = "no";
        }

        mysql_query("INSERT domainnames SET dns='".$domain_name."', available='".$availability."', timestamp='".$date."'")or die(mysql_error());

    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider wrapping these in double quotes `<input type=submit name=proses value=Check>` as in `<input type="submit" name="proses" value="Check">` and `<input type="text" name="domain">`

Comment: Also consider to have different pages rather than conditional-content single pages. Google for template engines, like "Smarty"

Comment: You don't have to use a huge form as an example to solve your problem.
Please -- and this refers to everyone -- keep your example code to a minimum. Thus it will be easier to 1) read the code and 2) reply to it, esp. with a correction of the code. Simple as that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Corrected code:
Display form only when we do not have form values submitted.
So, write your HTML code in `else` tag as following:

```
<div id="domain-name-check">

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['proses'])){
        $domain_name = "$_POST[domain]"."$_POST[suffix]";
        $arrHost = @gethostbynamel("$domain_name");
        $date = date('y-m-d');

        if(empty($arrHost)){
            echo "<h2>$domain_name is beschikbaar</h2> <a href='/offerte-aanvragen/".$domain_name."/'>Vraag een offerte aan</a>";
            $availability = "yes";
        }else{
            echo "<h2>$domain_name is helaas bezet</h2> <a href='/offerte-aanvragen/".$domain_name."/verhuizen/'>Verhuis uw domein</a>";
            $availability = "no";
        }

        mysql_query("INSERT domainnames SET dns='".$domain_name."', available='".$availability."', timestamp='".$date."'")or die(mysql_error());

    }
        else {
        ?>
        <h2>Is uw domeinnaam nog vrij?</h2>
    <form method='post' class="clearfix">
        <input type=text name=domain>
            <select name="suffix">
                <option value=".nl">.nl</option>
                <option value=".be">.be</option>
                <option value=".com">.com</option>
                <option value=".net">.net</option>
                <option value=".org">.org</option>
                <option value=".biz">.biz</option>
                <option value=".info">.info</option>
                <option value=".mobi">.mobi</option>
                <option value=".ws">.ws</option>
                <option value=".cc">.cc</option>
            </select>
            <input type=submit name=proses value=Check>
    </form>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvote for lack of explanation of what was changed, or why it fixed the code. No discussion of techniques or links to documentation. The answer to this question holds no value to the community.

Comment: Hi @michaelward82, thanks for downvoting. I got the point. From now, I will provide proper explanations, links, documentations. This is the glory of this site.

Comment: Then I will take back the downvote :) Hope you continue to enjoy using SO!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="domain-name-check">
    <?php if(!isset($_POST['proses'])){ ?><h2>Is uw domeinnaam nog vrij?</h2>
    <form method='post' class="clearfix">
        <input type=text name=domain>
            <select name="suffix">
                <option value=".nl">.nl</option>
                <option value=".be">.be</option>
                <option value=".com">.com</option>
                <option value=".net">.net</option>
                <option value=".org">.org</option>
                <option value=".biz">.biz</option>
                <option value=".info">.info</option>
                <option value=".mobi">.mobi</option>
                <option value=".ws">.ws</option>
                <option value=".cc">.cc</option>
            </select>
            <input type=submit name=proses value=Check>
    </form>
    <?php } //endif form submitted
    if(isset($_POST['proses'])){
        $domain_name = "$_POST[domain]"."$_POST[suffix]";
        $arrHost = @gethostbynamel("$domain_name");
        $date = date('y-m-d');

        if(empty($arrHost)){
            echo "<h2>$domain_name is beschikbaar</h2> <a href='/offerte-aanvragen/".$domain_name."/'>Vraag een offerte aan</a>";
            $availability = "yes";
        }else{
            echo "<h2>$domain_name is helaas bezet</h2> <a href='/offerte-aanvragen/".$domain_name."/verhuizen/'>Verhuis uw domein</a>";
            $availability = "no";
        }

        mysql_query("INSERT domainnames SET dns='".$domain_name."', available='".$availability."', timestamp='".$date."'")or die(mysql_error());

    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by restructuring the current code a bit:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['proses'])){
        # code ...
    }
    else {
?>
        <div id="domain-name-check">
        <!-- your form code goes here -->
        </div>
<?php 
    } //end of else block 
?>
```

Full code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['proses']))
{
    $domain_name = "$_POST[domain]"."$_POST[suffix]";
    $arrHost = @gethostbynamel("$domain_name");
    $date = date('y-m-d');

    if(empty($arrHost)){
        echo "<h2>$domain_name is beschikbaar</h2> <a href='/offerte-aanvragen/".$domain_name."/'>Vraag een offerte aan</a>";
        echo "AVAILABLE";
        $availability = "yes";
    }else{
        echo "<h2>$domain_name is helaas bezet</h2> <a href='/offerte-aanvragen/".$domain_name."/verhuizen/'>Verhuis uw domein</a>";
        echo "NOT AVAILABLE";
        $availability = "no";
    }

    mysql_query("INSERT domainnames SET dns='".$domain_name."', available='".$availability."', timestamp='".$date."'")or die(mysql_error());
} 

else 
{
?>
    <div id="domain-name-check">
    <h2>Is uw domeinnaam nog vrij?</h2>
    <form method='post' class="clearfix">
    <input type=text name=domain>
    <select name="suffix">
        <option value=".nl">.nl</option>
        <option value=".be">.be</option>
        <option value=".com">.com</option>
        <option value=".net">.net</option>
        <option value=".org">.org</option>
        <option value=".biz">.biz</option>
        <option value=".info">.info</option>
        <option value=".mobi">.mobi</option>
        <option value=".ws">.ws</option>
        <option value=".cc">.cc</option>
    </select>
    <input type=submit name=proses value=Check>
    </form>
    </div>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under your form tag,insert a hidden form field like this:

```
<form method='post' class="clearfix">
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="hideme" />
.................................
 .............................

</form>
```

Now under your $_POST section,use the following logic:

```
 if (isset($_POST['action'])&& ($_POST['action']=='hideme'))
 {
  //perform your intended task on submission
}else {

//Show My form code again

}
```

Simple!

Answer (score 0):

HTML code may be wrapped with PHP to conditionally show it.

Consider the following as a template for this type of functionality:

```
<?php if (condition) { ?>

    <p>HTML</p>

<?php } ?>
```

It's that simple.

In this instance, your condition will probably be

```
if (isset($_POST['proses'])
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `<h2>Is uw domeinnaam nog vrij?</h2>` with

```
if (!isset($_POST)){
       echo '<h2>Is uw domeinnaam nog vrij?</h2>';
}
```

this will make sure if form is not submitted then `h2` will visible to user
alternatively you can use Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
<?php

if (  isset( $_POST['field_name'] )  )
  {
  .... // submit
  exit();

  }

?>

<html>
<form ... action="" method="POST">
....
....
</form>
</html>
```